# How do you calculate the Tweedie prediction based on model coefficients?

Tags: r, tweedie-distribution

What is the formula to calculate the prediction for a Tweedie distribution using model coefficients? I am trying to manually calculate the prediction.

Below is my attempt at reproducible code.

```
library(tweedie)
library(statmod)

rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
cat("\014")  
outputdata <- read.csv("example.csv", header = TRUE)
attach(outputdata)

# Fit the glm
fit <- glm( y ~ log(Variable1), data=outputdata, family=tweedie(var.power=1.65, link.power=0) )
summary(fit) 

outputdata$predvals <- predict(fit, type = "response", newdata = outputdata)
write.csv(outputdata, "example output.csv", na = "", row.names = F)
```

The input data (example.csv) consists of one column as the independent variable (Variable1) and the second column the dependent variable (y).

The data is as follows:

> Variable1 y 1 0 2 0.13 3  0 4 0.05 5  0.01 6  0.21 7  0.03 8  0.1 9   0.32
>   10    0.16 11 0.16 12 0.08 13 0.03 14 0.13 15 0.15 16 0.2 17  0.25 18 0.32
>   19    0.14 20 0.19 21 0.26 22 0.17 23 0.34 24 0.23 25 0.29 26 0.16 27 0.1
>   28    0.23 29 0.28 30 0.45 31 0.18 32 0.23 33 0.14 34 0.16 35 0.29
>   36    0.28 37 0.16 38 0.34 39 0.14 40 0.31 41 0.12 42 0.33 43 0.14 44 0.3
>   45    0.53 46 0.23 47 0.18 48 0.64 49 0.3 50  0.36 51 0.38 52 0.41 53 0.26
>   54    0.12 55 0.35 56 0.12 57 0.41 58 0.04 59 0.23 60 0.71 61 0.09
>   62    0.32 63 0.23 64 0.41 65 0.19 66 0.58 67 0.14 68 0.27 69 0.42
>   70    0.55 71 0.42 72 0.41 73 0.29 74 0.23 75 0.19 76 0.27 77 0.19
>   78    0.23 79 0.24 80 0.42 81 0.5 82  0.41 83 0.15 84 0.34 85 0.38 86 0.4
>   87    0.37 88 0.17 89 0.22 90 2.24 91 0.17 92 0.15 93 0.34 94 0.15 95 0.4
>   96    0.16 97 0.52 98 0.48 99 0.41 100    0.24

The model output I get is:

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ log(Variable1), family = tweedie(var.power = 1.65, 
    link.power = 0), data = outputdata)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max
-1.50992  -0.38106  -0.04531   0.16910   2.25728

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    -3.17232    0.33346  -9.513 1.38e-15

log(Variable1)  0.49793    0.08646   5.759 9.75e-08

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass `glm()` the tweedie family the return value is a `glm` object. So you can use the `predict()` method or the `predict.glm()` method if you prefer to specify to any future readers of your code that this is a `glm`.

```
example(tweedie)
twdeReg <- glm(y~x, family=tweedie(var.power=1, link.power=1))
predict(twdeReg)
predict.glm(twdeReg)
```

In the predict family of functions you pass the argument `newdata=newDataName` to specify prediction on a new dataset, default behavior is to predict on the current data. Also, read `?predict` to see the 3 options of if you want prediction of the linear combination of predictors, on the y-space, or the other one which I've never found super useful.

---

Added from comment on the reply:

To get this manually you'll need to use the equation from `?tweedie` documentation that describes the link. The doc states: $\mu_i^q = \mathbb{E}(y_i|\vec{x}_i)^q = \vec{x}_i^T\vec{\beta}$ so if you want the expected value you'll need to calculate:

$$\mathbb{E}(y_i|\vec{x}_i) = (\vec{x}_i^T\vec{\beta})^{1/q},$$

where $q$ is the `link.power=1` value. so if `q=1` as the question is written simply take the product of the estimates times the coefficients and add up all of these products ( $\vec{x}_i^T\vec{\hat{\beta}}$ ) where the 'hat' denotes the estimate.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to manually calculate it. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: So with link.power=0 and my hypothetical variable coefficients, would the expected value be: exp[ a + b*log(var#1) + c*var#2 ] ^ (1/p) ?

Comment: @Frank H. ->  The doc states: "A value of zero for $q$ is interpreted as $\log(μ_i) = x_i^Tb$ where they use $b$ to refer to the estimated coefficients in the glm. So you do not need to take $1/p$ but the rest of the expression you have written in the comment is correct

Comment: @Frank H. -> to be fully clear if `link.power=0`, then the expected value would be:  exp[ a + blog(var#1) + cvar#2 ] in the notation used in this post.

Comment: I reduced the formula to just be a single continuous variable and cannot get a match with the formula. I added the numbers in the original post. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Frank H. -> maybe post a reproducible example of the error here (with simulated data if need be) and I can take a look, without that it is hard for me to say anything helpful.

Comment: @Frank H. what is the value of $p$ that you are using in the example posting above?

Comment: 1.71429. I added the code used to determine p in the OP.

Comment: I noticed in the call of the function the code calls using `y`, `log(variable#1)` but then another argument calls `data=training`. if you call `objects()` do you have `y` and `log(variable#1)` as different values than in `data=training`?

Comment: I added everything to the original post. Sorry that I don't know how to load the data so that it's more easily accessed.

Answer (score 1):

```
> summary(fit)

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ log(Variable1), family = tweedie(var.power = 1.65, 
    link.power = 0), data = outputdata)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-1.50992  -0.38106  -0.04531   0.16910   2.25728  

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    -3.17232    0.33346  -9.513 1.38e-15 ***
log(Variable1)  0.49793    0.08646   5.759 9.75e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Tweedie family taken to be 0.3136375)

    Null deviance: 34.712  on 99  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 25.218  on 98  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

> outputdata$predvals <- predict(fit, type = "response", newdata = outputdata)
> y_hat=exp(fit$coefficients[1]  + fit$coefficients[2]*log(Variable1) )
> all.equal(y_hat,outputdata$predvals)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Silly mistake as always - I was using log when I should've used ln.